# google chart's chart area white space issue

Tags: charts, removing-whitespace, google-visualization

am using google charts to show pie charts in my angular web application.  the issue is the white space around the pie chart.  if i edit the chartArea attributes, the whitespace around the chart remains same, but the size of actual pie is reduced.  becuase of which the legends are getting word wrapped.

because of this issue, am able to show only two pie charts in one row.  i want to show minimum 3 pie charts without wordwrapping the legends.  the main issue is with the whitespace around the pie chart.  how can i reduce that without reducing the size of pie chart.

in below pic, i have highlighted the whitespace in blue. how to reduce the whitespace so that it just ends after the legend.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Even if we move the legend around white space does not reduce.

Comment: @WhiteHat options = {
                    // title: response.data.responseData.metaData.chartTitle,
                    titleTextStyle: {
                        color: '#4c4c4c',
                        bold: true,
                        fontSize: 0
                    },
                    sliceVisibilityThreshold: 0,
                    colors: isPieChart ? [
                        '#6B2319'] : ['#003EA9'],
                    chart: {
                        //   subtitle: response.data.responseData.chart[1].chartData.label.endDate
                    },

Comment: chartArea: {
                        'width': isPieChart ? '85%' : '80%',
                        'height': isPieChart ? '85%' : '65%',
                        'left': '0',
                        'top':'0'

                    },
                    is3D: true,
                    legend: {
                        position: isPieChart ? 'right' : 'top',
                        //maxLines: 6,
                        alignment: 'center',
                        textStyle: {
                            fontSize: 11
                        }
                    }

Comment: @WhiteHat i was able to reduce the size using the chartArea and also the outer div wrapper.  i have another issue now... i am showing a column chart and the legend pagination is showing up.  any way i can remove the pagination and for all entries to be shown in same page?

Comment: Is this question abandoned?  What is the status?

Comment: @whitehat I was not able to remove it.

Comment: not able to remove the pagination in the column chart? how many legend entries?

Comment: like 70 entries... it shows up 10 per page...